# 2 software threads one "ordinary" core vs 2 threads on one hyperthreaded core

Tags: multithreading

I'm unsure about what advantage Intel's hyperthreading (and AMD's equivalent) gives.
Suppose in my program I have 2 threads that the scheduler happens to put on one core.
If that core is hyperthreaded what's the advantage?
Suppose that both threads do the same thing (identical code), does that make a difference.
If that scenario doesn't give the hyperthreaded CPU an advantage, what scenario does?

Answer (score 0):

In our programs we use operating system threads which are a kind of abstraction.
On hardware level it is more complex. Processor need to do a lot of things to run commands and some of the things just wast time of processor.

[Wiki definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) says **Hyper-threading works by duplicating certain sections of the processor—those that store the architectural state**

So we can easily imagine the case:

- processor need to load something to register
- to do not waste time while it's loading it's change execution context
  to another thread so **we can win some amount of processor time**

Comment: Thanks so much. Stackoverflow is an amazing site!